# How to callback function works in ajaxcall in meteor?

Tags: ajax, meteor, callback

I am calling to some third party API. in that I have to callback some function in response to some function. I am unable to callback in success but when I call it by name it runs successfully. I am using callback to make it generalize so when ever I want to callback something i just have to name it in request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
Meteor.methods({
 // The method expects a valid IPv4 address
 'geoJsonForIp': function (ip) {
   console.log('Method.geoJsonForIp for', ip);
   // Construct the API URL
   var apiUrl = 'http://www.google.com/iop/' + ip;
   // query the API
   var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl).data;
   return response;
 }
});
```

Hopefully this helps you.